# Rails 3 client_side_validations giving a compile error ( I am using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, client-side-validation

I am getting the below error when using client_side_validations...I have put my source below.. The form is nothing complex, it is a simple form I am using with devise...Can someone help me what is the issue..

Error:

```
compile error
C:/project/madhu_ar/app/views/profiles/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND
...rm_for(@profile), :validate => true do |f| @output_buffer.sa...
                              ^
C:/project/madhu_ar/app/views/profiles/new.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, 
expecting $end

My Source is like this :

<h1>Business Profile Setup </h1>
<%= form_for(@profile), :validate => true do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :businessname %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :businessname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :addressline1 %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :addressline1 %>
</div>
```

Regards
Madhukar

Answer (score 2):

Your closing parenthesis is in the wrong place, this:

```
<%= form_for(@profile), :validate => true do |f| %>
```

should be:

```
<%= form_for(@profile, :validate => true) do |f| %>
```

or just:

```
<%= form_for @profile, :validate => true do |f| %>
```

The [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) helper wants the object as the first argument and the options hash as the second; why say `form_for(@profile), :validate => true`, you're giving `form_for` its first argument and then following that method call with a comma and a symbol and that's invalid syntax.